# Pure Css slideshow containing texts

Tags: html, css

I want to create a slideshow with containing texts(paragraphs and headers) and the slideshow will be infinite(looping from 1st to last slide).Here is what i have done so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>




/**** slider ****/

#slider, ul
{
    height: 200px;
    background-color:rgb(205, 223, 207);
}

#slider
{
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 14px black;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}

#slider li
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
}

#slider ul
{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 9000px;
    transition: left .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: left .3s linear;
    -o-transition: left .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s linear;
    margin-left: -25px;
  font-family: century gothic;
  color: #666;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-animation {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    2% {opacity:1;}
    20% {left:0px; opacity:1;}
    22.5% {opacity:0.6;}
    25% {left:-600px; opacity:1;}
    45% {left:-600px; opacity:1;}
    47.5% {opacity:0.6;}
    50% {left:-1200px; opacity:1;}
    70% {left:-1200px; opacity:1;}
    72.5% {opacity:0.6;}
    75% {left:-1800px; opacity:1;}
    95% {opacity:1;}
    98% {left:-1800px; opacity:0;} 
    100% {left:0px; opacity:0;}
}

#slider ul
{
    -webkit-animation: slide-animation 25s infinite;
}

/* use to paused the content on mouse over */

#slider ul:hover
{
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

/*** Content ***/

.slider-container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 550px;
  min-height: 180px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.slider-container h2
{
    color: orange;
  text-shadow: -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

.slider-container  p
{
    margin: 10px 25px;
    font-weight: semi-bold;
    line-height: 150%;
    color:black;

}

/* use to paused the content on mouse over */

#slider ul:hover
{
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section id="slider">
<ul>
    <li>
    <div class="slider-container">
    <h2>Header 1</h2>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slider-container">
       <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slider-container">
       <h2>Header 3</h2>
        <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slider-container">
      <h2>Header 4</h2>
        <p>Paragraph 4</p>
    </div>
    </li>

</ul>
</section>
</body>
```

A few problems i have so far:

Is there any way i can make the slide change from one to another by typing something in the url(for example a slide-unique id)??(if that requires unique #id for each slide i can edit css rules easily).

How can i add a small number at the bottom of each slide to represent which slide we are currently looking?(1st page ,2nd page etc.)

I am using latest Chrome edition.

Answer (score 0):

Just give every slide div an id and do linke this:
Mypageurl.com/slideshow#slideid

This will jump to the correct slide

Important! You need to make shure every slide can be viewed from Mypageurl.com/slideshow, otherwise it wouldnt work, you can do this with overflow-z:scroll on your main slide container if the slides are placed next to eachother, this is also the easyest way to do navigation later on

Comment: I am confused. How can i make an html doc a Mypage.com?

Comment: Or just index.html 

Comment: I thought it was an online slideshow you where making :)

Comment: I am making the same thing (with fancy animations), mine is online, if you send me your code, I can have a look at it for you

Comment: The code i have pasted is the code i want to use/improve.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following links i hope they will be able to help you better :
[Gallery CSS](http://benschwarz.github.io/gallery-css/#item-1)

[Github: CSS Slider](https://github.com/drygiel/csslider)

[W3Schools Sildeshow](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)